# How to list all word press pages and their URLs, filtered by Draft vs Published?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in need of creating a report on our WordPress pages. The report should consist of the page title and its URL, linked to the actual page. However, we dont want to list all pages. We need to filter them based on Draft or Published.

Is this possible to list pages filtered by Draft or Published? (the author does not matter)

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //display title, url filtered by draft or published 
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this one is using `get_posts` while second one is using `WP_Query`

Argumnet for both ways it will be same.

```
    $args=array(  
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'post_type' => 'page',
         'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'draft' )
    );
```

**Method - 1 - get_posts()**

```
    $pageslist = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach($pageslist as $key=>$val)
    {
        $pageid=$val->ID;
        $link= get_permalink($pageid);
        $title=$val->post_title;
        echo "Page title: {$title}<br>Page id: {$pageid}<br> Link:{$link}<br><br>";
    }
```

**Method - 2 - WP_Query**

```
    $page_data = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if ( $page_data->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $page_data->have_posts() ) : $page_data->the_post();
        ?>
                <p> Page Title:
          <?php   the_title();?></p>
               <p> Page ID:
          <?php the_ID();?></p>
                <p> Page link:
          <?php the_permalink();?></p>
                <br><br>
                <?php 
         endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
       else :  esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); 
    endif;
```

Comment: first one didnt work. Second one listed title, id, and link. I needed just title (as a link). thanx, ill see if I can edit it and make it work

Comment: Yes, I got 2nd one to work just fine by changing line too:   <p> <a href=" <?php the_permalink();?> "><?php   the_title();?><a></p>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and pass your arguments to display the pages which are are published or drafted:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'draft' )
);

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the key here is to use `post_status` to filter out the posts.

Comment: hmm, only listed two titles. no links